# Outlook Add-in Hostname not getting correctly in Mac

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

I am working on getting host name to identify which platform Add-in runs. I followed [Provides diagnostic information to an Outlook add-i](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics). Its return following string in each platform.

```
var hostName = Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostName;
```

1.OWA - OutlookWebApp

2.Outlook on windows - Outlook

3.Outlook on mac - Outlook

But the documentation says return string can be one of the following values: Outlook, Mac Outlook, OutlookIOS, or OutlookWebApp.

For Outlook on mac i am expecting a Mac Outlook or OutlookIOS, but i am returning a Outlook. Is that a expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the *office.context.platform* to differentiate between the platforms.

Comment: yes, It is working and each platform and returns OfficeOnline, PC, Mac. Is it not working  using Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostName?.  And I couldn't  find any document for office.context.platform.